# How to override and rename properties of User built-in model in Loopback Framework

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using the loopback framework to create a RESTful API for my application.

Following the documentation, I create my own Customer Model extending the built-in model User.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

**How can I rename and remove some properties from this built-in model?**

```
    {
      "name": "Cliente",
      "plural": "Clientes",
      "base": "User",
      "idInjection": false,
      "strict":"true",
    ...
    }

    {
      "name": "User",
      "properties": {
        "realm": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "username": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "password": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "email": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "emailVerified": "boolean",
        "verificationToken": "string"
      },
     ...
  }
```

I reached the results modyfing the loopbacks models inside the **node modules**, but this solution does not seem the right way, is there a way to config this in my code instead change loopback base models?

Comment: I think you need to use i18n solutions not changing variable names

Comment: IMO, the API itself shouldn't be language specific, but rather the client using the API should concern itself with being localized. That being said - if you are extending a model, then the properties will come through as is - you can't necessarily delete them or change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is "rename" a property, am I correct?
If so, you can do the following:

```json
"senha": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true,
      "required": true,
      "index": true,
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "password"
      }
    }
```

Notice that I have a "postgresql" attribute, which depends on your database connector. Check it [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file). Inside that attribute I have a "columnName", which is the real name of that column in my database. So "senha" is the new name of that attribute.

For hiding the username property, you could do the following in the root object:

```
"hidden":["username"]
```

Your final file should look something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Cliente",
    "plural": "Clientes",
    "base": "User",
    "idInjection": false,
    "strict": "true",
    "properties": {
        "realm": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "username": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "senha": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true,
            "postgresql": {
                "columnName": "password"
            }
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "emailVerified": "boolean",
        "verificationToken": "string"
    },
    "hidden": ["username"]
}
```